# Black box below select dropdown in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am seeing the black box below select dropdown whenever i click select dropdown field first time after some movement in form (like displaying dynamic error message banner at the top of the form). This issue happened only in chrome.

I am using bootstrap + jquery in my front end.

[image]

Code:

```
<b:form-btn-group label="${siteLabel}" labelFor="sites" cssBody="col-sm-4" cssBtn="col-sm-1" button="addsite" buttonTxt="${addTxt}" cssClass="display-none required">
                <select id="sites" name="sites" class="form-control" disabled>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <c:forEach items="${sites}" var="site">
                        <option value="${site.name}">${site.name}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </b:form-btn-group>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/2060/

Comment: Build a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added JSFiddle with issue field.

Comment: Can't find the black box in my chrome.. latest chrome..

Comment: I tried same link with couple of my friends PC and issue was there. May be what is the version your using?

Comment: Breaks on mine as well - Version 54.0.2840.71 m - "Google Chrome is up to date."

Comment: Supposedly it's a security feature https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/Q4Rt6d0C4Qo/Ygq70wYTBgAJ

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=553274

Comment: In the productforums says, it was resolved in "Version 54.0.2840.59 m". I also has same version in my machine. But still i am seeing issue.

Comment: Same issued happened with me. Its showing some time.  @Mohan

Answer (score 1):

This issue appeared after I changed some settings in flags page. 
I disabled zero copy rasterizer in flags and that fized it.
If you don't have zero copy rasterizer activated or you already disabled it, then you can also try disabling things related to GPU like HW accceleration...

Comment: Correct I can confirm I had opened a Chromium issue on this exact thing, and also found that flag to be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a problem with hardware acceleration. I had the same problem and it was very very annoying.

Instructions to effect solution found here:
http://www.solveyourtech.com/turn-hardware-acceleration-google-chrome/

Answer obtained from this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/641098/blank-select-options-on-chrome-chromium-ubuntu-14-04

For whatever reason, this may fail depending on your chrome version. But it worked for me.